# Is it haram to even mention "pig"?

Tags: halal-haram, terminology, animals, pork

Okay, so I was about to learn a new computer tool which might be one of the major things I would be working on in my future career course. The name of the tool is ***"PIG"***. [What is Pig?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_(programming_tool))

As I was just preparing to start up this morning a thought stormed my mind raising the question if I am pushing any Islamic boundaries by taking up this tool named ***"PIG"***. Am I in the wrong somehow?

Anybody who can clarify regarding this point!

I am aware of the pig eatery rules in Islam but want to know regarding this particular situation.

Comment: The pig is still an animal like any other animals, we are just not allowed to eat it but other than that no other rule is given. We cannot eat lions too, why would you think that you should not speak about lions? Or pigs? They're still very beautiful creations of Allah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muslims are not allowed to eat pig (Qur'an [5:3](https://quran.com/5/3), [6:145](https://quran.com/6/145), [16:115](https://quran.com/16/115)), and most scholars consider pig impure (see [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/172600)).  There's some other restrictions, such as not wearing pig leather ([Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/22713)), not keeping a pet pig ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=122702)), and selling pig meat ([AskTheSheikh.com](http://www.askthesheikh.com/what-are-the-rules-on-touching-or-selling-bacon-and-pork/)).

As for saying the word "pig"?  That sounds absurdly extreme, since even the Prophet is reported to have said the word in Arabic.  As a random example, from Sahih Muslim 2260 ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/41/11)):

> ... He who played Nardashir (a game similar to backgammon) is like one who dyed his hand with the flesh and blood of swine.
>
> مَنْ لَعِبَ بِالنَّرْدَشِيرِ فَكَأَنَّمَا صَبَغَ يَدَهُ فِي لَحْمِ **[خِنْزِيرٍ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%AE%D9%86%D8%B2%D9%8A%D8%B1)** وَدَمِهِ

Comment: I get it what you intend to say but the thing is I have heard (heard only, no proof of it crossed my eyes ever) that mentioning _pig_ in certain languges (like in urdu) is considered unlikely. Several legends go like there is a sort of punishment for saying the word (in specific language) in this lifetime.

[**pig** in urdu](http://hamariweb.com/dictionaries/pig_urdu-meanings.aspx)

Can you throw some light on this?
I would feel guided.

Comment: @HashirBilal Khanzir is even mentioned in the Quran, so to call it haram to say pig would be at least a (bad) innovation (bidah). Remember we read the quran in prayer, so the word khanzir would be recited even there if one pleases. The legends you speak about seems to be cultural and has nothing to do with Islam.

Comment: @KiliseThank you so much. Now its crystal clear. There are no doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Bismillahir rahmanir raheem,
All praises and thanks be to Allah the Almighty, the Owner of the Worlds, and the All-seeing, All knowing, Eternal.

No, it's not haram to mention pig...since the word "Khinzir" (Pig in arabic) is also mentioned in Quran. Consuming pig, selling pig meat, pig cutlery, wearing pig leather, etc is haram. But only mentioning pig is not haram.

Wallahu A'alam (And Allah knows best)

Answer (score 0):

no its not it is a creation of allah it is haram and impure but that does bot mean saying pig is haram

Comment: " it is haram and impure but that does bot mean saying pig is haram" This is self-contradictory. What is haram of it is eating its meat.

Answer (score -1):

no it is haram to say "pig" because it is napak in islam and they used it in  the Qu'ran because how else would we teach other muslims what pig is.pig is very bad as it is forbidden in islam.